# Expose list of GeoJSON through REST API in a Java Spring Boot project

Tags: geojson, java, rest

We need to expose APIs which would list uploaded GeoJSONS at S3 bucket for a particular user.

I plan to take below steps

1. Storing all GeoJSONs to S3 bucket
2. As USER logs in

   - Read his GeoJSONs from S3 location as String
   - Convert these String as JSONObjects of Java
   - Return a list of these JSONs
3. FrontEnd then to take care of rendering these GeoJSONs

Is there a better approach for taking care of such problems?

Comment: GeoJSON is a poor format for storing data in as it is a text based unindexed format which is slow to read and parse.

Comment: @IanTurton Please suggest me alternate then

Comment: Depends on your use case - databases are usually good

Comment: @IanTurton But the GeJSON file is big around 3-4 MB. 
What DB would you suggest. Will Postgres be a good fit with column type as as 'json' ?

Comment: While that is big for a text file it is tiny in a geospatial sense. I like PostGIS but there are plenty of other databases you could use.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.